# Как сделать так чтобы при нажатии мышки экран начал сам менятся бесконечно?

Tags: python, pygame

Код дисплея и картинки:

```
def run_game():
    game = True
    while game:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                quit()
        display1()
        scream.play()
        pygame.display.flip()

def display1():
    while True:
        display.blit(disp, (0, 0))
        for e in pygame.event.get():
            while e.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONUP:

                display.blit(smile, (0, 0))

                display.blit(smile2, (0, 0))

                display.blit(smile, (0, 0))
                display.blit(smile2, (0, 0))
                pygame.display.update()
```

при нажатии кнопки на мышке картинка не меняется и потом программа вылетает без ошибок

Answer (score 1):

Вы два раза отрисоваваете `smile` и `smile2` и лишь потом обновляет экран, вам надо после каждой отрисовки добавит `pygame.display.update` либо добавить цикл `for`

```
for smile_ in (smile, smile2):
    display.blit(smile_, (0, 0))
    pygame.display.update()
```